# Joda DateTime, unable to change Year

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime

I am using the Joda DateTime function for Java to add 30 minutes to a set time.
For example 10:00:00 to 10:30:00. However, the code below is not working. The main two issues are
1.  When the year is set to 2012,  the myFormat.parse function automatically set the date to 2014 (see logcat below). 
2. plusMinutes(30) is not adding 30 minutes to the time. Can you look over my code and let me know how to fix it?

Java code:

```
package com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.Alerts;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.R;
import com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.EventList.DataView;
import com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.EventList.EventDetails;
import com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.sqllite.DatabaseSqlite;

public class AlertDetails extends Activity {

    Integer id;
    String name;
    String date;
    String startTime;
    String endTime;
    String location;
    int alertState;
    Bundle bundle;
    String alertTime;
    String s;

    private String update_alarmTime;
    String eventYear;
    String eventDay;
    String eventMonth;

    DatabaseSqlite entry = new DatabaseSqlite(AlertDetails.this);

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alertview);

        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        alertTime = bundle.getString("alertTime");
        alertTime = "10:00:00";// for testing


        // set Date
        eventYear = date.substring(0, 4);
        eventDay = date.substring(5, 7);
        eventMonth = date.substring(8, 10);
        mDateDisplay.setText(eventDay + "-" + eventMonth + "-" + eventYear);

        String eventdate = eventDay + "/" + eventMonth + "/" + eventYear;
System.out.println("event date "+eventdate);


        String currentDate;
        SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date1 = null;
        DateTime dt;

        currentDate = eventdate+ " "+alertTime;
        System.out.println("current date "+currentDate);

        try {
            date1 = myFormat.parse(currentDate);
            System.out.println("date formated: "+date1);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        dt = new DateTime(date1);
        dt.plusMinutes(30);
        System.out.println(" origional time is " +alertTime+" new time is "+dt);
```

Logcat:

```
 02:43:16.844: D/dalvikvm(1027): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2421 objects / 165200 bytes in 137ms
08-09 02:43:18.355: I/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gcm.demo.app/.Alerts.AlertDetails (has extras) }
08-09 02:43:18.405: I/System.out(1027): event date 05/30/2012
08-09 02:43:18.415: I/System.out(1027): current date 05/30/2012 10:00:00
08-09 02:43:18.415: I/System.out(1027): date formated: Thu Jun 05 10:00:00 GMT+00:00 2014
08-09 02:43:18.605: D/dalvikvm(1027): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2743 objects / 261528 bytes in 43ms
08-09 02:43:18.665: D/dalvikvm(1027): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 216 objects / 242000 bytes in 43ms
08-09 02:43:18.905: D/dalvikvm(1027): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1461 objects / 314440 bytes in 45ms
08-09 02:43:19.305: D/dalvikvm(1027): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3043 objects / 276440 bytes in 55ms
08-09 02:43:19.945: D/dalvikvm(1027): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5365 objects / 354056 bytes in 54ms
08-09 02:43:19.955: I/System.out(1027):  origional time is 10:00:00 new time is 2014-06-05T10:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: If you have the correct year, month, and date, why aren't use using the DateTime constructor?

Comment: where `String date` is initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*1) Why 30 mins weren't added?*
Method `dt.plusMinutes(30);` don't added 30 minutes to `dt` instance. Instance `dt` is **immutable**. Method `dt.plusMinutes(30);` creates new instance of `DateTime` that is greater than `dt` on 30 minutes.
So:

```
dt = new DateTime(date1);
dt.plusMinutes(30);
```

is wrong!
Should be

```
dt = new DateTime(date1).plusMinutes(30);
```

or

```
dt = new DateTime(date1);
DateTime greaterDate = dt.plusMinutes(30);
```

*2) Why year = 2012?*

your pattern is `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`
your date is `"05/30/2012 10:00:00"`
30 months? :-)
Change pattern on `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`